# Policy on Removing Old Answers

Tags: discussion, answers, old-answers

Long ago, I wrote an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30368420/how-to-remove-python-in-usr-local-bin/30369372#30369372) in retrospect I wish I hadn't: it provides the right behavior in the short-term, but at the cost of likely difficult and troublesome debugging later (especially if someone changes the default Python from 2 to 3, or similar). Furthermore, there are better ways (setting variables in `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bash_aliases`, for example) of doing the same behavior. However, the answer is currently the "accepted" answer, so I am wondering if the best course of action is to add a disclaimer, delete the post, or some other form of action?

Comment: In the case of this specific question, you have the cover of it also being marked as off-topic, so it's unlikely anyone will scroll down to see your answer anyway.

Comment: @JoeC, unfortunately, that question has been viewed more than 17k times, and continues to get views.

Comment: We always evaluate current usefulness, not past or future. We want up to date answers which are maintained for useful questions.

Comment: Do you know enough to fix it? I always improve my accepted answers when I learn something new that makes me realize I should add or modify something.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Sounds to me like the right action is this particular case is to just add a prominent disclaimer.

Rationale: Based on what you describe here, it seems some people, even if they were to know the limitations/consequences of the solution in your answer, would still find the solution useful—and thus you should leave it up to them to choose whether to use it or not.

But you also should actually tell readers the limitations/consequences, as you’ve described them here—and so, to let people what know they’d be getting themselves into, add a prominent disclaimer to the question (with wording similar to what you have here but with appropriate detail).

Comment: Absolutely this. Sometimes a hack is all you need. Other times, understanding how the hacks work can give you valuable insight into the problem/tool. Adding the disclaimer gives everyone the best of both worlds: you keep the information there, but you also make it obvious what the downsides are. Couldn't have said it better myself. Only thing I am a bit apprehensive about is abusing quote formatting to add a disclaimer, since it isn't really a quotation.